# How to block stdin for a child process and ignore its stdout?

Tags: rust

I was trying to build a YouTube streamer using Rust that uses mpv player. I've managed to extract URL of music video from the YouTube search page.

I have set up an input loop to take user's commands. Actions are taken according to user commands. When the user specifies `play thisSong`, the music video's URL is extracted and saved as a string. Now,  I want to start a process by calling mpv player. The output of mpv player should be ignored, and the player should play music in the background, and the user should be back to prompt, from where he can supply commands again.

I tried to set it up, but the problem was that as soon as the`mpv` child process starts, it starts to take commands supplied by the user to my `main` program. I want `mpv` to ignore those commands.

```rs
let mut youtube_mpv = match Command::new("mpv")
        .arg(song_url)
        .arg("--no-video")
        .arg("--ytdl-format=worst")
        .arg("--really-quiet")
        .arg("&")
        .stdout(Stdio::null())
        .spawn()
{
    Err(_why) => exit(1),
    Ok(process) => process,
};

println!("Playing {} from YouTube", song_name);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `.stdin(Stdio::null())`.

By default, the subprocess will inherit all streams from the parent. If you don't want that, either `pipe` them (to interact with the subprocess via stdin/stdout) or `null` them (to redirect to / from `/dev/null`).

Incidentally I don't think this:

> ```
> .arg("&")
> ```

makes any sense. It's going to pass an `&` argument to mpv, which mpv is going to assume is a file, look up, fail to find, and trigger an error. Assuming you eventually `wait()` on the mpv subprocess, it'll always report failure.

Comment: Thanks for the remark about `&`. Many people don't realise that this is just a textual *convention* for the shell when it analyses a command line, and this does not end up into the underlying `execve()` system call.

Comment: @prog-fh I'd call it an operator rather than a convention (that's also [how opengroup defines it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03_02)) but yeah.